# My Android-Emulator displays emulator error

Tags: java, android

I made an Android Application. Eclipse isn't reporting me what errors are there in my code.

But if I run my project then emulator displays:

[emulator error http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20121106/466GCZH9.png](http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20121106/466GCZH9.png)

My Java code is (`MainActivity.java`):

```
package ru.startandroid.develop.AppLog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
    Button myBtnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtnCancel);
    Button myBtnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtnOK);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.myBtnCancel: 
            myText.setText("Нажата кнопка Cancel"); 
        break;
        case R.id.myBtnOK: 
            myText.setText("Нажата кнопка ОК"); 
        break;
     }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below:

Declare variables at instance level and assign values inside `onCreate()`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    TextView myText = null;
    Button myBtnCancel = null;
    Button myBtnOK = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
        myBtnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtnCancel);
        myBtnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtnOK);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `findViewById()` after calling `setContentView()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    TextView myText;
    Button myBtnCancel;
    Button myBtnOK;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
        myBtnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtnCancel);
        myBtnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtnOK);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the Widgets (TextView and Buttons) calling `findById` after the `setContentView` method, because depends of it:

```
TextView myText;
Button myBtnCancel;
Button myBtnOK;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
    myBtnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtnCancel);
    myBtnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtnOK);
}
```